# sum of entry of $A^{-1}$ in matrix $10\times 10$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $10\times 10$ matrix.

and entry on diagonal equal to $1$ and othet entry equal to $-1$.

I need sum of entry of $A^{-1}$.

can you help me?

Comment: Typing your matrix [here](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx) gives the result as  $-\frac {5}{4} $.

Answer (score 4):

Denote by $N$ the matrix consisiting only of $1$'s. We have $A=2I-N$. Then we compute, using $N^2=10N$ that $A(8I-N)=16I$, so that
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{16}{(8I-N)}.
$$
Hence the matrix $A^{-1}$ has $\frac{7}{16}$ on the diagonal, and any other entry equal to $-\frac{1}{16}$. The sum of all entries of $A^{-1}$ therefore is $-\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: I think your $\frac{7}{10}$ is not correct. Otherwise, very elegant.

Comment: Just a typo, corrected!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x$ denote the column vector whose entries are all $1$s. You're trying to compute $x^TA^{-1}x$. Note that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$; it's easy to compute $Ax = -8x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix $A$ has $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ off the diagonal. Conjecture that $A^{-1}$ has $a$ on the diagonal and $b$ off the diagonal. Calculating $AA^{-1}_{ii}$ for $i=1,\ldots,10$ gives $a-9b=1$. Calculating $AA^{-1}_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ gives $-a-7b=0$. Solving these two equations and calculating $10a+90b$ gives your answer.